# Django - Attach PDF generated by a view to an email

Tags: django, pdf, email-attachments, django-email

This question has some elements [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31695742/django-attach-pdf-to-an-e-mail-which-was-generated-by-a-view), but no final answer.

There is view generating a PDF with easy_pdf

```
from easy_pdf.views import PDFTemplateResponseMixin

class PostPDFDetailView(PDFTemplateResponseMixin,DetailView):
    model = models.Post
    template_name = 'post/post_pdf.html'
```

Then, I want to attach this generated PDF to the following email :

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Post)
def first_mail(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        user_email = instance.client.email
        subject, from_email, to = 'New account', 'contact@example.com', user_email
        post_id = str(instance.id)
        domain = Site.objects.get_current().domain
        post_pdf = domain + '/post/' + post_id + '.pdf'

        text_content = render_to_string('post/mail_post.txt')
        html_content = render_to_string('post/mail_post.html')

        # create the email, and attach the HTML version as well.
        msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
        msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
        msg.attach_file(post_pdf, 'application/pdf')
        msg.send()
```

I also have tried this one:

```
   msg.attach_file(domain + '/post/' + post_id + '.pdf', 'application/pdf')
```

Answer (score 6):

I was looking for a way to attach an easy_pdf generated PDF without saving a temp file as well. Since I couldn't find a solution elsewhere, I suggest a short and working proposal using [easy_pdf.rendering.render_to_pdf](http://django-easy-pdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#easy_pdf.rendering.render_to_pdf):

```
from easy_pdf.rendering import render_to_pdf
...
post_pdf = render_to_pdf(
        'post/post_pdf.html',
        {'any_context_item_to_pass_to_the_template': context_value,},
)
...
msg.attach('file.pdf', post_pdf, 'application/pdf')
```

I hope it'll help if you are still interested by a way to do this.

Comment: Working Like a charm. Thanks, Brother.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it helps, but I used [EmailMessage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/email/#the-emailmessage-class) built-in to attach PDFs I created for reporting to emails I sent out:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail, EmailMessage

draft_email = EmailMessage(
            #subject,
            #body,
            #from_email,
            #to_email,
)
```

Option 1:

```
# attach a file you have saved to the system... expects the path
draft_email.attach_file(report_pdf.name)
```

Option 2:

```
# expects the name of the file object
draft_email.attach("Report.pdf")
```

Then, sends like you already have:

```
draft_email.send()
```

Some initial thoughts:  it seems like you are trying to use attach_file to attach a file from the system, but it isn't on the system.  I would try using `attach` instead of `attach_file`, if I am reading your code correctly, since the pdf is in your memory, not in LTS on the system.

Comment: I think the problem comes because the PDF is generated when the view is requested, so it can not be attached to the email. What do you think about that?

Comment: I didn't have an issue using the attach when the file isn't created... Might be worth trying.  Assuming the file is still open and in cache when it tries to attach it to the email. Can you share your errors?

Comment: Using easy_pdf, the PDF is not saved somewhere. It is only generated. So the file report.pdf does not exist.

Comment: I would try using attach() then, since it doesn't expect the file to exist.  Check the docs for the nitty gritty on why, if you're interested:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/email/#the-emailmessage-class

Comment: Here's another thread that might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789669/dynamically-generate-pdf-and-email-it-using-django